# Bound on graph domination number when min degree is 7

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I have a graph $G$ whose minimum vertex degree is $\delta=7$.
I am seeking an upper bound on the [domination number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) $\gamma(G)$
in terms of the number of vertices $n$ of $G$.
I found a paper by
Edwin Clark, Boris Shekhtman, Stephen Suen, and David Fisher, 
"Upper bounds for the domination number of a graph," *Congressus 
Numerantium*, 132:99–124, 1998 ([CiteSeer link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.54.6194)),
that implies a bound of about $0.31 n$ (more precisely, $(18286568 / 58640175)n$).
I was hoping for a smaller upper bound.  Perhaps there have been advances since that paper?
Any pointers to relevant literature would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, if the graph has nice structure, the bound can be improved. Let me know if you are still interested in this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the complete history is as follows. For an arbitrary graph with $n$ vertices and minimum degree $k$, the result has been shown to be at most
$$
\frac{n[1+\ln(k+1)]}{k+1}
$$
by Arnautov<sup>1</sup> (1974) and Payan<sup>2</sup> (1975), but the articles were written in Russian and French, respectively.  For $k=7$, this gives a bound of $0.384930n$.   In 1985, Caro and Roditty improved this bound slightly to $0.325283n$ when $k=7$.  For this second result, see *Caro, Y.; Roditty, Y.*, On the vertex-independence number and star decomposition of graphs, Ars Comb. 20, 167-180 (1985), [ZBL0623.05031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0623.05031).  Next comes the result you mentioned: $0.311844n$ in 1996 (not 1998).  So, unfortunately, I think the answer is that your bound is the best known at this time.  See also the discussion at the beginning of *Xing, Hua-Ming; Hattingh, Johannes H.; Plummer, Andrew R.*, [**On the domination number of Hamiltonian graphs with minimum degree six**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aml.2007.10.023), Appl. Math. Lett. 21, No. 10, 1037-1040 (2008), [ZBL1160.05326](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1160.05326) for the most recent paper published on this topic.

A short proof of the result of Arnautov and Payan can be found in
*West, Douglas B.*, Introduction to graph theory, New Delhi: Prentice-Hall of India (ISBN 81-203-2142-1). 608 p. (2005), [ZBL1121.05304](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1121.05304), on page 117, which uses the greedy algorithm (by Alon).  Discussions are also found in papers for $k=2,3,4,5,6$ by various authors (I'm guessing this may not be of use to you but these cover some history).  There is a new paper by Kostochka and Stocker<sup>3</sup> for cubic graphs ($5n/14$) which indicates that some authors are still working on this problem.  This is everything that has been done (as far as I know).  Let me know if you learn more.

Another approach would be to use the independent domination number $i(G)$ since $\gamma(G) \le i(G)$ for any graph $G$.  I think the most recent result here is $0.18329n$, *but* this is only for a $7$-regular graph.
Not sure if this helps.  The result is *Duckworth, W.; Wormald, N. C.*, [**On the independent domination number of random regular graphs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0963548305007431), Comb. Probab. Comput. 15, No. 4, 513-522 (2006), [ZBL1121.05084](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1121.05084).

---

1. *Arnautov, V. I.*, Abschätzung der äußeren Stabilitätszahl eines Graphen mit Hilfe des Minimalgrades der Ecken, Prikl. Mat. Programm. 11, 3-8 (1974), [ZBL0297.05131](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0297.05131).
2. *Payan, C.*, Sur le nombre d’absorption d’un graphe simple, Cah. Cent. Étud. Rech. Opér. 17, 307-317 (1975), [ZBL0341.05126](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0341.05126).
3. *Kostochka, A. V.; Stocker, Christopher*, [**A new bound on the domination number of connected cubic graphs**](http://semr.math.nsc.ru/v6/p465-504.pdf), Sib. Èlektron. Mat. Izv. 6, 465-504 (2009), [ZBL1299.05252](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1299.05252).

Comment: There is also a nice probabilistic proof of the Amautov & Payan result in Lesniak & Chartrand. Or at 
East was in the 3rd edition.

Answer (score 5):

See this article, it provides the best bound till date:

*Bujtás, Csilla; Klavžar, Sandi*, [**Improved upper bounds on the domination number of graphs with minimum degree at least five**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00373-015-1585-7), Graphs Comb. 32, No. 2, 511-519 (2016). [ZBL1339.05280](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1339.05280).

> #### Abstract
>
> An algorithmic upper bound on the domination number $\gamma$ of graphs in terms of the order $n$ and the minimum degree $\delta$ is proved. It is demonstrated that the bound improves best previous bounds for any $5 \leq \delta \leq 50$. In particular, for $\delta =5$, Xing et al. (Graphs Comb. 22:127–143, [2006](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00373-015-1585-7#ref-CR24)) proved that $\gamma \leq 5n/14 < 0.3572n$. This bound is improved to $0.3440 n$. For $\delta=6$, Clark et al. (Congr. Numer. 132:99–123, [1998](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00373-015-1585-7#ref-CR9)) established $\gamma < 0.3377n$, while Biró et al. (Bull. Inst. Comb. Appl. 64:73–83, [2012](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00373-015-1585-7#ref-CR3)) recently improved it to $\gamma < 0.3340n$. Here the bound is further improved to $\gamma < 0.3159n$. For $\delta=7$, the best earlier bound $0.3088n$ is improved to $\gamma<0.2927n$.